# How to create borders on TreeViewItems?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TreeView that uses a Hierarchical Data Template.

I want to create borders around the Parent Elements with borders on the child elements.

So it might look something like:

```
----------------------------------------
|                                      |
|                Big Border            |
|    |-----------Child Border---- --|  |
|    |------------------------------|  |
|                                      |     
|                                      |
----------------------------------------
```

This is XAML so far:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 10, 0, 0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="PitcherStyling" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAce}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Team.Players}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewStyle}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LongRelief}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Attributes}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Max Innings}" Style="{StaticResource GroupTypeStyling}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:StartingPitcher}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Attributes}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Strikeout Pitch}" Style="{StaticResource PitcherStyling}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

So, the Parent Elements will be Starting Pitcher and Long Relief Pitchers will always be children of Starting Pitcher.

So I would want a border that acts as a container for a Starting Pitcher and all of the Long Relief Pitcher Children and for each of these Long Relief Children, they have their own mini border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give treeviewitem a template with a border round the default.
I extracted the template for a treeviewitem ( select one, in properties click the box over on the right of Miscellaneous > Template ).
Made this the template in a default style for a treeviewitem and added the border.
Giving me:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <ToggleButton.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                    <Border Background="Transparent" Height="16" Padding="5" Width="16">
                                                        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Data="M0,0 L0,6 L6,0 z" Fill="White" Stroke="#FF818181">
                                                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                                <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                                                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                        </Path>
                                                    </Border>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF595959"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF262626"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF27C7F7"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FFCCEEFB"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <MultiTrigger>
                                                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF1CC4F7"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF82DFFB"/>
                                                        </MultiTrigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </ToggleButton.Style>
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">
```

With some test data, this looks like:

[image]

Comment: Could there be an image as to what this would look like?

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: It is difficult to tell where I would need to edit my code. Would it be possible to remove the code not related to the bordering?

Comment: The markup inside the Window.Resources is all styling on the treeviewitem. Replacing a template is all or nothing. So. No it's not practical to remove code not related to bordering. At least not without significant side effects.

Comment: If you have no window.resources section in your window at the moment, just grab that entire tag and content and paste into your window. If you do have one, grab the style tag just within window resources and paste that into your existing window.resources.

Comment: Fair enough. It does that I would like. Thank you. I hit the green arrow.